# How to prove $x^{x/(1+x)}/(1+x)\geq1/2$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

I need to show that $\frac{x^{\frac{x}{1+x}}}{1+x} \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\geq0$.

I am fairly certain this statement is true, but have no idea how to go about proving it.

I know that it attains a local minimum of 1/2 at $x=1$. It also seems to hold when I plot it out, decreasing from $[0,1]$  and increasing after, it seems to approaches 1 as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Bernoulli $$\frac{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{1+x}=\frac{1}{(1+x)\left(1+\frac{1}{x}-1\right)^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}\geq\frac{1}{(1+x)\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\cdot\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Yes that's a typo! I will fix that. This is perfect, thank you so much, I have never heard of Bernoulli's inequality but it seems very useful!

Answer (score 2):

If we call this function $f(x)$ then since $f(1)=\frac12$ you must have intended to say that $f(x)\geq\frac12$ in your statement.

Additionally $f(x)$ does have a local minimum (not local limit, whatever that means) of $\frac12$ at $x=1$ and is increasing for $x>1$.  This follows from finding $f'(x)$ and finding that $f'(1)=0$ even though it is a bit messy.

That is all you need.

Graphing the function shows it approaches $1$ not $2$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$. To prove this, L'Hopital's rule did not seem to work so perhaps someone else can fill this in by other means but it's not needed to prove your claim.

Added: as often happens, the above answer appeared just as I posted this!

Comment: Where is the mathematics? You wrote an english story in a computation question.

Comment: Only details of $f'(x)$ omitted; seemed ok in this context. Maybe not to all.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{x+1}\quad \implies \quad f'(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{x}{x+1}}}{(x+1)^3} \log (x)$$

The first derivative cancels only once at $x=1$.

$$f(1)=\frac 12 \qquad f'(1)=0\qquad f''(1)=\frac 18 $$

So, this is a minimum.

When $x$ is large
$$f(x) \sim 1-\frac{\log (x)+1}{x}$$ which is the curved asymptote.

**Edit**

For building the asymptotics, write
$$\log(f(x))=\frac x{x+1}\log(x)-\log(x+1)$$ Using Taylor expansion
$$\log(f(x))=-\frac{\log (x)+1}{x}+\frac{2 \log (x)+1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Taylor again
$$f(x)=e^{\log(f(x)) }=1-\frac{\log (x)+1}{x}+\frac{\log ^2(x)+4 \log (x)+2}{2
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Comment: Is there a "short" way to get $f'(x)$? I got it by brute force (quotient rule, $ln$ of both sides etc.).  Rather than calculate $f''$ I noted that $f'$ changes from negative to positive at $x=1$.  Additionally, would you mind showing how you got the approximation in the last statement? Thank you.

Comment: @AlgTop1854. Have a look at the edit

Comment: Thanks for adding this detail.  Very helpful.  I also took the opportunity to recheck my calculation of $f'(x)$, was a little cleaner the second time and (thankfully) matched the way you expressed it.