# Can anyone help prove or disprove that $\frac{\Pi_i x_i ^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{1+\sum_i x_i} \geq \frac{1}{N+1}$, where $x_i>0$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, jensen-inequality

I was hoping the generalize this result: [How to prove $x^{x/(1+x)}/(1+x)\geq1/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4817649/how-to-prove-xx-1x-1x-geq1-2/4817886#4817886)

I believe that the following inequality holds:

$\frac{\Pi_i x_i ^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{1+\sum_i x_i} \geq \frac{1}{N+1}$

Where $x_i>0$ and $N$ is the number of elements.

**Edit**
Here is my attempt (trying to use the method from linked question)

By bernoulli’s inequality

$x_i ^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}= \frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{1}{x_i} -1\right)^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i} } 
\geq 
\frac{1}{1+\left( \frac{1}{x_i} -1\right)  \left( \frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}\right) } =\frac{1+\sum_i x_i}{2-x_i +\sum_i x_i}$

thus

$\frac{\Pi_i x_i ^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{1+\sum_i x_i} \geq 
\frac{\left({1+\sum_i x_i}\right)^{N-1}}
{ \Pi_i \left(2-x_i +\sum_i x_i\right)}$

Then by the AM-GM inequality

$\Pi_i \left(2-x_i +\sum_i x_i\right)
\leq
\left(\frac{\sum_i \left( 2-x_i +\sum_i x_i\right)}{N}\right)^N
=
\left(\frac{2N +(N-1)\sum_i x_i }{N}\right)^N
=
 \left( 2 +\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\sum_i x_i \right)^N$

thus

$\frac{\Pi_i x_i ^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{1+\sum_i x_i} \geq 
\frac{\left({1+\sum_i x_i}\right)^{N-1}}
{ \Pi_i \left(2-x_i +\sum_i x_i\right)}
\geq 
\frac{\left({1+\sum_i x_i}\right)^{N-1}}
{ \left( 2 +\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)\sum_i x_i \right)^N}
$

Comment: Have you tried generalizing Michael's solution?

Comment: I attempted to but could only attain $\frac{\Pi_i x_i ^\frac{x_i}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{1+\sum_i x_i} \geq 
\frac{\left({1+\sum_i x_i}\right)^{N-1}}
{ \Pi_i \left(2-x_i +\sum_i x_i\right)}$

Comment: And unfortunately that expression tends to 0 at large $N$ (which doesn't violate the original hypothesis, because Bernoulli's inequality only holds at some points)

Comment: Are you sure about this? In the case of $x_i=1 \forall i$ I was under the impression that both sides of the expression (as well as the third expression in my edit) are equal to $\frac{1}{N}$, which is giving me some hope, as I conjecture that the LHS attains its minimum when $x_i=1 \forall i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's decompose the denominator of the $LHS$ into $n+1$ terms:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\prod_i x_k ^\frac{x_k}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{1+\sum_i x_i} 
&= \frac{\prod_i x_k ^\frac{x_k}{1+\sum_i x_i}}{(1+\sum_i x_i)^{\frac{1}{1+\sum_i x_i}}\cdot \Pi_k\left((1+\sum_i x_i)^{\frac{x_k}{1+\sum_i x_i}}\right)} \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}  \right)^{\frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}} \prod_{k=1}^n  \left(\frac{x_k}{1+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}  \right)^{\frac{x_k}{1+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}} 
\end{align}$$

Denote $y_0 = \frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ and $y_k = \frac{x_k}{1+\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}$ for $k = 1,...,n$, then the problem is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}&\prod_{k=0}^n y_k^{y_k} \ge\frac{1}{n+1} \\
&\iff \sum_{k=0}^n y_k \ln(y_k) \ge \ln \left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right)\\
& \iff  \frac{1}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n y_k \ln(y_k) \ge \frac{1}{n+1} \cdot\ln \left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right)\tag{1}\end{align}$$
given $y_k> 0$ and $\sum_{k=0}^ny_k=1$.

To prove $(1)$, it suffices to apply the Jensen's inequality to the convex function $f(t)= t\ln(t)$  (indeed, $f(t)$ is convex as $f''(t) = 1/t >0$ for $t>0$):
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}  \sum_{k=0}^n y_k \ln(y_k) \ge \frac{\sum_{k=0}^ny_k}{n+1}\cdot \ln  \left(\frac{\sum_{k=0}^ny_k}{n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{n+1} \cdot\ln \left( \frac{1}{n+1} \right)$$

The equality occurs if and only if all $y_k$ are equal, or $x_1=x_2=...=x_n = 1$.